# How to rearrange x-axis columns in bar plot GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, x-axis

I am trying to make a bar plot showing the hatching mass affecting outcome of birds. THe graph is fine but the x-axis are all jumbled up. I would like the x-axis to be from small to big in number/hatching mass.

I have used the following code.
[It produces this graph- see the axis I was talking about?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHPqZ.png)

```
H<- read.csv("H.csv")
library("ggplot2")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
H %>%
  drop_na(last_rank) %>%
  filter(chick_outcome == "Released" |
           chick_outcome == "Died") %>%
  count(last_rank, chick_outcome) %>%
  group_by(last_rank) %>%
  mutate(n= n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot()+aes(last_rank, n,fill= chick_outcome, label= paste0(round(n,2),
                                                                    "%"))+
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity')+
  geom_col()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.9))+
  geom_text(position = position_stack(0.5))+
  labs(title = "Mass before hatching affecing chick outcome",
       x= "Mass before hatching interval (g)",
       y= "Outcome percentage (%)")+
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("red", "green"),
                    name= "Chick outcome")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust= 0.5,size = 17, family = "Times new roman"))
```

Comment: Hi Jana, welcome to Stack Overflow. The issue is coming from your `factor` levels. R orders factor levels alphabetically and numerically, but that is usually not what we want. This site demonstrates how to reorganize `factor levels`: https://www.statology.org/reorder-factor-levels-in-r/ Try `levels()` on your "Mass before hatching interval (g)" variable and then reassign the correct ordering like they do in example from Statology.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the reply! I have used your advise and have been able to rearrange the x-axis. But now I want to still have a stacked barplot (as in my attached image in my oiginal question). Do you perhaps know how I can make my stacked barplot. So the "Deceased" and "Released" occurance is present?

Answer (score 0):

H Jana, see if this helps you.  I took a subset of your data for an example, but this may get you closer to what you want.

```
chicks<-
data.frame(
group = factor(rep(c("105-109", "70-74", "95-99"),2), levels=c("70-74", "95-99", "105-109")),
proportion = c(c(.9, .5366, .8092), 1-c(.9, .5366, .8092)),
label = factor(c(rep("Released",3),rep("Died",3)), levels=c("Released","Died"))
)

> chicks[order(chicks$group, chicks$label),]
    group proportion    label
2   70-74     0.5366 Released
5   70-74     0.4634     Died
3   95-99     0.8092 Released
6   95-99     0.1908     Died
1 105-109     0.9000 Released
4 105-109     0.1000     Died
```

The variables that I am using are not the same as in your data set and so you may have to modify my code.

```
ggplot(chicks, aes(fill=label, y=proportion, x=group)) + 
          geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
          scale_fill_manual(values= c("green", "red"), name= "Chick outcome")
```

I get this:

[image: stacked bar plot with chicks data]

If you would like to have the percentages printed in the green and red areas as in your example, I would suggest that you look at this page: [How to add percentages to a stacked bar plot using a tibble](https://community.rstudio.com/t/create-a-percentage-stacked-bar-chart/26223). If you have trouble, you are welcome to ask a new question in Stack Overflow. Good luck!